# Getting perldoc to work in notepad++ and NppExec

Tags: perl, notepad++, nppexec

I am immersing myself into the world of Perl for the first time. I figured the easiest way was to integrate using notepad++, which is my preferred editor. I went ahead and installed the ActiveState self extracting installer. I then pointed NppExec to my perl directory by typing:

perl "$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)"

As a script "Run Perl", saved, then added a macro using this procedure

http://paul.atc.informatica.gsf.nl/resources/Perl_with_Notepad.pdf

I can run Perl scripts using the perl compiler. However, perldoc does not work erroring with:

Can't locate object method "perldoc" via package "perldoc" (perhaps you forgot to load "perldoc"?) at C:\Users...

This is because my perldoc and compiler are actually in c:\perl\bin (or whatever)

How do I switch the file path to point to the right directory? Thank you so much. I am a complete noob at this.

Edit: To add more information, perldoc works fine if i call

```
perldoc perldoc
```

using the command prompt. It does not work when i write a script in notepad++ and attempt to complile. Both the cmd prompt and notepad++ will compile scripts correctly.

Comment: did you add 'perldoc' as an function-key shortcut?

Comment: No I did not. I tried testing this by typing perldoc perldoc. That's when I got the error. When I typed the same into a cmd prompt it worked as expected.

Comment: and by typing, you mean at a CMD prompt?

Comment: @LenJaffe Yes, it works under a windows cmd prompt. If i try to do it as a .pl script in notepad++ it does not. I can compile in both notepad++ and windows cmd prompt.

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with notepad++, can you provide more detail about it not working as a notepad++ script please.

Comment: When I try to compule a script using perldoc I get the following error in the console:

    NPP_EXEC: "Run Perl"
    c:/perl/bin/perl   "perl_intro.pl"
    Process started >>>
    Can't locate object method "perldoc" via package "perldoc"              (perhaps you forgot to load "perldoc"?) at perl_intro.pl line 1.
    <<< Process finished. (Exit code 255)
    ================ READY ================

Comment: and perl_into.pl just says 'perldoc perldoc'?

Comment: `perldoc` is not a Perl function. It is a command line program that finds the correct piece of documentation from installed modules and displays it (usually on a console). You can't use it in a Perl script. (`perldoc perldoc` is parsed as indirect object syntax, trying to invoke a method called `perldoc` on the string `"perldoc"`, therefore looking for a package called `perldoc`, which doesn't exist. The command should work fine when executed in a shell (e.g. cmd)).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perldoc is not a part of the Perl language. It is a program that is part of the core distribution.  You'll likely find a perldoc.bat in your ActivePerl install if you look for it.

So that's why:

```
 perldoc perldoc
```

works from the command line (because that's how it is intended to be invoked. But fails miserably when you ask Perl to execute 'perldoc' command.  It tries valiantly to find a method, defined somewhere in all of the modules that have been included, but finding none, tells you so.

So if you want to write a Perl program to execute perldoc, you could use something like this:

```
  print `perldoc perldoc`
```

But you're much better off using a bat file, or its equivalent in your version of windows.

Comment: Okay that makes more sense. So I guess it's like when I type "help math" in MATLAB in the command window? Anyways, I will just leave a command window open from now on. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome..and welcome to Perl. All your dreams will now come true :-)